# Ubuntu 18.04.4 - Systemd service that works on very first boot

Tags: boot, command-line, bash, systemd, services

What I want to achieve is that a new service would start immediately at the first boot to install a line of programs and setup some configurations for the raspberry pi to avoid doing this manually each time I want to create a new rPi with the following programs.

Using Ext2 I can add/overwrite files that are installed on the sd-card in the files that are usually not accessible on a windows operating system.

I have a bash script named firstbootsetup.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Bump! I'm your first-boot script."
```

And I have a systemd service called firstboot.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=This is first boot service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/firstbootsetup.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After the service is manually enabled using:

```
sudo systemctl enable firstboot.service
```

And a reboot has been done I can look in the journal

```
sudo journalctl -fu firstboot.service
```

to see that the script is executed and echoes the line from the bash scrip every 10 seconds.
This verifies that it does work after being enabled.

I have looked at [systemd.preset — Service enablement presets](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) but have without luck tried to add enable in the config files specified in the paths. Using my system I have presets in the following paths:

```
/lib/systemd/system-preset/90-systemd.preset
/usr/lib/systemd/user-preset/90-systemd.preset
```

These two files have different enables but adding firstboot.service to either of them does not enable the file.

Making this work with init.d and a bash script might also fix my problems if these can run commands to enable the systemd services.

Comment: You might be better off using cloud-init.

Comment: I've got it to work with cloud-init. Thank you for the hint :) 
This is my first question. Should I let it stay here just like this or should I create an answer on how I solved my problem or should it delete the question?

Comment: Maybe somebody could come up with a solution to the problem described here, so it's worth keeping. You could still post what you ended up doing as answer, since somebody else might go down the same path and find this.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer please! I've looked at `systemd-firstboot(1)` but it doesn't seem to ship on Ubuntu 20.04.